# How can I get an array of values from a list of checkboxes, and send these values to a controller action using AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

List of checkboxes generated onto the view:

```
<div class="row" id="muniTable">
    @for (var x = 0; x < Model.Municipalities.Count; x++)
    {
    <div class="col-3">
        <label asp-for="@Model.Municipalities[x].Selected">
            <label class="kt-checkbox kt-checkbox--brand"><input type="checkbox" id="muniBox" asp-for="@Model.Municipalities[x].Selected"> @Model.Municipalities[x].Text<span></span></label>
        </label>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Municipalities[x].Text" />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Municipalities[x].Code" class="muni-code" />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Municipalities[x].ID" />
    </div>
    }
</div>
```

Example of a generated div containing the checkbox and hidden inputs that are needed

```
<div class="col-3">
    <label for="Municipalities_0__Selected">
        <label class="kt-checkbox kt-checkbox--brand"><input type="checkbox" id="muniBox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Selected field is required." name="Municipalities[0].Selected" value="true"> 002 - TOWN OF TEST<span></span></label>
    </label>
    <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Text field is required." id="Municipalities_0__Text" name="Municipalities[0].Text" value="002 - TOWN OF TEST">
    <input type="hidden" class="muni-code" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Code field is required." id="Municipalities_0__Code" name="Municipalities[0].Code" value="002">
    <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="Municipalities_0__ID" name="Municipalities[0].ID" value="1">
</div>
```

Javascript code to get the hidden values and send them to the controller using AJAX (In the example above, the needed value is '002'):

```
$("#muniTable :checkbox").change(function (e) {
    //Array of municipality codes
    var munis = new Array();
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.muni-code').each(function () {
            //This section of the code does not work
            //I need to get the values of all the hidden municipality "Codes" here, and add them to the munis array.  I am currently using $(this).parent().parent(), but can't seem to find a way to get the values that I need from all of the hidden inputs that are related to each municipality object.
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: { muniSelections: munis },
            url: '@Url.Action("TAGetDistrictsByMunicipality", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString())',
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `each` loop to iterate over all checkboxes which is checked and then use `$(this).closest('.col-3')` to find the div which is closest to your checkboxes ,using this we can get all other values needed with checkboxes.Also,in below code snippets i have created `JSON Array` for values which we get .You can pass same to ajax or can convert it to `JSON String`.

Here is demo code :

```js
$("#muniTable :checkbox").change(function(e) {
  //Array of municipality codes
  var munis = new Array();
  //checking value of checked
  $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val(); //value of checkbox
    var $slector = $(this).closest('.col-3');
    var text = $slector.find(".text").val(); //getting value of test
    var municode = $slector.find(".muni-code").val(); //geting value of municode
    var ids = $slector.find(".ids").val(); //getting value of ids
    item = {}
    item["ids"] = ids;
    item["checkboxes"] = value; //adding values 
    item["text"] = text;
    item["municode"] = municode;


    munis.push(item); //adding item to array
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(munis)) //convert json to string
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      muniSelections: JSON.stringify(munis)
    },
    url: '@Url.Action("TAGetDistrictsByMunicipality", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString())',
    success: function(data) {

    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="muniTable">
  <div class="col-3">
    <label for="Municipalities_0__Selected">
        <label class="kt-checkbox kt-checkbox--brand"><input type="checkbox" id="muniBox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Selected field is required." name="Municipalities[0].Selected" value="true"> 002 - TOWN OF TEST<span></span></label>
    </label>
    <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Text field is required." id="Municipalities_0__Text" name="Municipalities[0].Text" class="text" value="002 - TOWN OF TEST">
    <!--added class="text"--->
    <input type="hidden" class="muni-code" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Code field is required." id="Municipalities_0__Code" name="Municipalities[0].Code" value="002">
    <!--added class="muni-code"--->
    <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The ID field is required." class="ids" id="Municipalities_0__ID" name="Municipalities[0].ID" value="1">
    <!--added class="ids"--->
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <label for="Municipalities_1__Selected">
        <label class="kt-checkbox kt-checkbox--brand"><input type="checkbox" id="muniBox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Selected field is required." name="Municipalities[1].Selected" value="true"> 001 - TOWN OF TEST<span></span></label>
    </label>
    <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Text field is required." id="Municipalities_1__Text" name="Municipalities[1].Text" class="text" value="003 - TOWN OF TEST">
    <input type="hidden" class="muni-code" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Code field is required." id="Municipalities_1__Code" name="Municipalities[1].Code" value="003">
    <input type="hidden" class="ids" data-val="true" data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="Municipalities_1__ID" name="Municipalities[1].ID" value="2">
  </div>
</div>
```